# Using multidimensional arrays and sorting

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, canvas

In HTML I've created a simple interface to be used to enter an employee’s name, age and position in the company and that information will then be displayed on the screen. I would also like the ability of being able to sort that information being displayed by the employee’s name or the employee’s age, using multidimensional arrays.

Set up event listeners to execute appropriate functions when the buttons in the HTML are clicked.

I need this to be setup programmatically (with an event listener) and not with the HTML `onclick` attribute.

The `addRecord` function is to be called when the user clicks the ‘Add Record’ button. It will take the values from the HTML fields (‘Name’, ‘Age’, ‘Position’) and add them to a multidimensional (2d) array in that order. It then needs to update the HTML canvas with the record details.

The `writeRecords` method needs to handle the code for writing the array of employee details to the HTML canvas. The array should only be written to the canvas here and not anywhere else in the code. The style the information is written in must be appropriate to fit comfortably on the canvas on a single line of text, whilst still being readable. The output must also contain labels as well as the information, ie. “Name: Amelia, Age: 23, Position: Manager”.

The `sortName` function must be implemented to sort the employee details by the
employee’s name and update the details in the canvas. This must be done when the user
clicks on the ‘By Name’ button in the sorting options.

The `sortAge` function must be implemented to sort the employee details by the employee’s
age and update the details in the canvas. This must be done when the user clicks on the ‘By
Age’ button in the sorting options.

Here's my current HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>52DA session 5</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body onload="setupCanvas()">
<div id="container">
<h1 id="firstHeading" class="blueTxt">Employee Records</h1>

<canvas id="employeeRecords" width="400" height="400">
<p>This example requires a browser that supports the 
<a href="http://www.w3.org/html/wg/html5/">HTML5</a> canvas feature.</p>
</canvas>
<h3>Sort</h3>
<button id="sortByName">By Name</button>
<button id="sortByAge">By Age</button>
<br/>
<br/>

<form>
<fieldset>
    <legend><h3>Employee Details Entry</h3></legend>
    
        <p><label>Name: <input type="text" id="name" /></label></p>
        <p><label>Age: <input type="text" id="age" /></label></p>
        <p><label>Position: <input type="text" id="position" /></label></p>
    
    <input type="button" id="addRecord" onclick="" value="Add Record"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<br />

</div>
<script src="../js/employee_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

which just displays the input form and canvas that the details will be displayed to,
heres my javascript skeleton, which I've cleaned back to basics after code wasn't working at all.

```
function setupCanvas(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('employeeRecords');
var ctx;
    
if (canvas.getContext) {
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
    ctx.rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    ctx.fill();     
}
    
function sortName(){
    
}

function sortAge(){
    
}

function addRecord(){
            
}

function writeRecords(){
            
}

function resetArray(){
    
}

}
```

How should I implement this?

Comment: This question is too broad. You're looking for someone who'll implement a bunch of functions handling form (is it an interview question or homework?). Have you even really try to implement it? Ask specific question when you'll be stuck (and search the web first) instead of asking for the whole solution :)

Comment: im not looking for the whole code, im just looking to find out what types of functions code id use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are a part of the Document Object Model (DOM) Level 3 and every HTML element contains a set of events which can trigger JavaScript Code. When the page loads, it is called an event. When the user clicks a button, that click is an event. You can set specific functions to run when the user performs an event. These functions listen for an event and then initiate the function. You can integrate the event listeners by identifying the element and adding the event listener as a method. You can also add event listeners using a method called addEventListener(). But some browsers don't support it.  A method that handles an event is called an event handler.

```
//
//
/* 
* employee_script.js
*/

var employeeA = new Array();
var employee = new Object();
var employeeList = [];
var employeeListA = [];
var name;
var age;
var position;
var type = 3;
var canvas;
var ctx;

function setupCanvas(){
//alert("1");
canvas = document.getElementById("employeeRecords");
if (canvas.getContext) {
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
    ctx.rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    ctx.fill();     
}
//alert("2");
document.getElementById('sortByName').onclick = function() {
    type = 0;
    //sortName();
    //writeRecords();
};
document.getElementById('sortByAge').onclick = function() {
    type = 1;
    //sortAge();
    //writeRecords();
};
document.getElementById('addRecord').onclick = function() {
    addRecord();
};
//alert("3");
function sortName(){
    type = 0;
    employeeList.forEach(function (empl){
        name = empl.name;
        age = empl.age;
        position = empl.position;
        employeeA = new Array(name, age, position);
        employeeListA.push(employeeA);
    });
    var y = employeeListA.length;
    if(y > 1)
    {
        employeeListA.sort();
    }
}

function sortAge(){
    type = 1;
    employeeList.forEach(function (empl){
        name = empl.name;
        age = empl.age;
        position = empl.position;
        employeeA = new Array(age, name, position);
        employeeListA.push(employeeA);
    });
    var y = employeeListA.length;
    if(y > 1)
    {
        employeeListA.sort();
    }   
}

function addRecord(){
     employee.name = document.getElementById('name').value;
     employee.age = document.getElementById('age').value;
     employee.position = document.getElementById('position').value;
     employeeList.push(employee);
     employee = new Object();
     writeRecords();
}

function writeRecords(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    ctx.font = "15px Aril";
    var y = 10;
    resetArray();
    employeeListA.forEach(function (empl){
        if(type === 1)
        {
            var m = "Name: "+ empl[1] +", Age: "+empl[0]+", Position: "+empl[2];
        }
        else
        {
            var m = "Name: "+ empl[0] +", Age: "+empl[1]+", Position: "+empl[2];
        }
        ctx.fillText(m, 10, y);
        y += 18;
    });
}

function resetArray(){
    employeeListA = [];
    if(type === 0)
    {
        sortName();
    }
    else
    {
        if (type === 1)
        {
             sortAge();
        }
        else
        {
            employeeList.forEach(function (empl){
            name = empl.name;
            age = empl.age;
            position = empl.position;
            employeeA = new Array(name, age, position);
            employeeListA.push(employeeA);
            });
        }
    }
}

//var testb = document.querySelector('button');
//testb.addEventListener('click', event => {
//alert(event +" "+ event.target);
//});
//var button = document.querySelector('button');
//button.addEventListener('click', testE);
//function testE()
//{
//    alert("Test...Event");
//}
document.getElementById('sortByName').addEventListener("click", function(event){
    alert("sortByName. "+ event);
    type = 0;
    writeRecords();
});
 document.getElementById('sortByAge').addEventListener("click", function(event){
    alert("sortByAge. "+ event);
    type = 1;
    writeRecords();
});
document.getElementById('addRecord').addEventListener("click", function(event){
   alert("addRecord. "+ event);
   //addRecord();
});
}

//alert("Employee Records.");
window.onload = function(){
//alert("Start");
setupCanvas();
//alert("Done");
};
//

//
```

Comment: You don't understand how long i've been looking for this exact answer man!
It was so hard to word it like i wasnt just trying to cheat a test etc. because i literally had no clue where to start! Thanks so much, going to go back and look thru each code and understand how and why everything works, you're a legend man. <3